# Setting EditText to single line makes it lose its focus after pressing enter

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, adp

I use an EditText in my code and compare its content to a string when clicking on a button.
Unfortunately doing this with the enter key through onKey causes problems because enter creates a
line break.
I used:

```
setSingleLine(true);
```

to prevent this. But now pressing enter leads to the EditText losing its focus.
Why does it behave like this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this `android:lines="1"` in your layout xml for EditText.

This will consider the Enter Key as new line and focus will not loose. Although existing text might not be visible due to only one line, as it moved upword and get hidden.

Comment: Thank you, using this instead of setSingleLine(true) does the trick!

Comment: I agree. Of course I will mark this, but the system didn't yet allow me to do so. Thanks again :)

Comment: This answer does not prevent the line break. Is there no way to prevent the line break while keeping the focus?

Answer (score 1):

Set the EditText as the next focus of itself:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/input"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Didn't worked dude. I am testing my app on Nexus 5 - Android-M 6.1.1